# JQuery Mobile 3 Dropdown DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to add a 3 dropdown datepicker to my project.

Does anyone have and url or sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) <-- I like this option IMO
- [Datepicker](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/)

Comment: I like DateBox too but it's giving major problems when I open differnet instances of it. They both open up .. really strange stuff. As far as Datepicker, looks nice but it's very unstable and I had to drop it :o/

Comment: hmm I'm currently developing a site where I have four different datebox elements and have no issues. I would double check if the id and name are unique

Answer (score 3):

You could also try [Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com), a customizable datepicker optimized for touch devices